# Suddenly lost ssh capability from Mac to Debian Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, mac, debian, virtual-machine, xorg

I hope this is the right forum because this problem seems to be more of a 'system' issue vs a 'software' issue...
I had ssh capability working perfectly from my MacBook to my Debian Linux virtual machine.  Then with the hope of running GRASS GIS on the VM, I changed my ssh call on my MacBook from:

```
ssh -v -l skirby -p 2222  127.0.0.1
```

to

```
ssh -v -l skirby -p 2222 -Y  127.0.0.1
```

so I could see my GIS visualizations in the VM on my Mac
and it looked like it might work, but then this change to the ssh call popped up a window on my Mac saying there was a 'Quartz' update, which I went ahead and did, then rebooted both the Mac and the VM.  But now when I try either of the ssh calls above, it dies instantly with:

```
Connection reset by 127.0.0.1 port 2222
```

So, I thought perhaps the ssh daemon needed to be restarted on the VM, so I tried:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```

and

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

but both error out with:

```
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

but I don't know how to find out what the 'error' is.  Not sure if the Quartz update on the Mac is now throwing things off.
When I do:

```
ps -ef|grep ssh
```

on the VM, I see:

```
ssh-agent -O -a /run/user/1000/openssh_agent
```

Does that imply that ssh is alive and well on the VM?
As an aside, am I crazy to want to run GRASS GIS on the VM?
Any ideas on this very welcome...

Comment: I don't think you said which VM system you're using to run your Debian image. Is it VirtualBox? Parallels Desktop? VMWare Fusion? Anyway, did you check your VM software's settings, to make sure the virtual network setup between the host OS and the guest OS is correct?

Comment: `ssh-agent` is a program that caches credentials for the ssh client; it has nothing to do with *serving* ssh. Serving ssh would be `sshd`, or maybe something else listening and starting `sshd` on demand (I'm not familiar with how Debian does this). Run `ss -ltn` on the VM and see if it lists a listener with [something]:2200 in the "Local Address:Port" column.

Comment: I'm running VirtualBox.  And I think I have things right, i.e., I am using Port Forwarding: name:ssh, protocol: TCP, Host Port:2222, Guest Port: 22.  When I run ss -ltn on the VM, I see: state: LISTEN, Recv-q: 0, Local Address:Port set to 127.0.0.1:631, Peer Address:Port set to 0.0.0.0:* Process:(blank).  Not sure how the VM began listening on port 631.  I assume I need to change this to listening to port 2222 on the VM?  If so, how to enact this?

Comment: Port 631 is normally used for IPP ("Internet Printing Protocol), so it's not relevant here. Since you have forwarding from port 2222 to port 22, you *should* be seeing a listener on port 22 of the VM. If nothing's listening on port 22, you don't have the ssh service running on the VM, and you need to troubleshoot it there. Since it's on the VM, it's extremely unlikely that the Quartz update has anything to do with it.

Comment: Thx for all the good info.  I went to the extreme length of rebuilding my VirtualBox image.  Then when I tried to ssh to the Linux image it said unrecognized key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts, then I said yes to update it.  Now it is working.